# How can I set struts.custom.i18n.resources properties to a specific folder?

Tags: properties, struts2

Java 1.6, Struts 2.0.11, Windows OS

What configurations do I need to make in `struts.xml` to place module-specific labels based properties file outside `src` package folder?

Reason: Group all internationalization-based properties in seperate module-based folder?

```
WEB-INF
   |_classes
   |   |__com 
   |        |__xyz
   |            |__Hellofoo.class
   |
   |__ struts.xml   
   |
   |__props
        |__xyz
            |_ en.properties [ English Labels ]
               jp.properties [ Japanese Labels]
               spn.properties[ Spainish Labels ]
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you have to specify this either in struts.xml file or in property file like

```
struts.custom.i18n.resources=global-messages, image-messages
```

or in xml file like

```
<constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="global-messages, image-messages" />
```

Alternatively you can use some sort of `Listener` to customize it as per your need.

IMO text resources should be organized according to region and package, but that's a matter of choice.

Comment: Hi
>>either in struts.xml file or in property file

Most of the Struts2 Developers place the "i18n.resources"  files along with *.java in n Respective packages ...

<constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="com.xyz.jp.properties" />

which is a normal practice in STRUTS2 for the run time label replacement process.

How ever in My case I would like to place the Files outside the Java Package [ as described in the above sketch ].

What exactly configuration should be done?......

Comment: best bet is to go for listener in such cases

Comment: Hi

Listener process is for Run time Label selection process 
jp.properties [ Japanese Labels]
spn.properties[ Spainish Labels ]

Comment: can't you do like creating a listener which load your resource bundle at server startup???? impliment `ServletContextListener` and than inside `contextInitialized` method use `LocalizedTextUtil` class of struts2 to load the resources.Though i have not tried but can always explore

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution

first in `struts.properties` `struts.custom.i18n.resources=globalMessages`
then, add the below code to the your StartupServlet or some other place that will execute where the server start

```
URL[] urls;
try {
    File file = new File("/your path");
    URL url = file.toURI().toURL();          
    urls = new URL[]{url};

    ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls);
    LocalizedTextUtil.setDelegatedClassLoader(cl);
    LocalizedTextUtil.addDefaultResourceBundle("globalMessages");
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Now this is not really an answer to your specific question. However i think it can be useful for people(like me) who stumble across this page with the question "How can I set struts.custom.i18n.resources properties to a specific folder (inside the src folder, but not right below it)

Now when i set the following in struts.properties, it does not work

```
struts.custom.i18n.resources=resources/locale-bundles/label-values,resources/locale-bundles/error-values
```

However if i set it in struts.xml, it does. (No idea why)

```
<constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources"    
value="resources/locale-bundles/label-values, resources/locale-bundles/error-values" />
```